# Elasticsearch limit count result

Tags: elasticsearch, count, pagination

How in Elasticsearch to limit count result to maximum of 1000?

So, If count have 400 results, then it respond with 400, if count have 1200, it repond with 1000.

We need to show a pagination, pagination only show 5 index on page, examples
1 2 3 4 5
3 4 5 6 7
4 5 6 7 8

so when we show page with index 5, we need to show pagination
3 4 5 6 7
2 pages before and 2 pages after
so, when we show page with index 5 we need to know only if page with index 6 and 7 exist

Comment: what you've tried?

Comment: Just GET /twitter/_doc/_count?q=user:kimchy

Comment: Seriously... [one search away](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html)

Comment: @Frank and it will return the count of all possible results without limit?

Comment: Set size parameter to 1000 in the query

Answer (score 0):

By default the [response body of a search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_the_search_api.html) will give you:

1. Various pieces of meta information including `hits.total`, which is the number of total hits for your query.
2. By default the top 10 results for your query.

Even when you are paging (and keep in mind that deep pagination is costly and should be avoided), `hits.total` will show you the total hits.

Setting a maximum value of the hits (showing 1,000 when you have 1,200 in your example) is IMO not the role of your datastore. Just just the min function of whatever programming language you are using: `Math.min(hits.total, 1000)`

Answer (score 0):

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-limit-count-result/127157/11
Discussion on elasticsearch forum